# Проблема с чтением шрихкода I2OF5

Tags: c#, терминал, штрихкод

Есть 2 терминала Motorola MC9090  и Motorola MC9190. Изначально под MC9090 было написано приложение которое считывает штрихкоды и работает с SQL БД. На МС9090 все работает отлично, на МС9190 проблема - не считывается штрихкод типа I2OF5 (min - 6, max - 8). Изменяю базовые значения(14 и 10 соотвественно) при помощи данного куска кода(на МС9090):

```
myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.MinimumLength = 6;
myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.MaximumLength = 8;
```

Пробовал передавать полный список параметров вот так (уже на MC9190):

```
myReader.Parameters.CodeIdType = CodeIdTypes.None;
myReader.Parameters.ScanType = ScanTypes.Foreground;
myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.MinimumLength = 6;
myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.MaximumLength = 8;
myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.Redundancy = true;
myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.CheckDigitScheme = I2OF5.CheckDigitSchemes.None;
myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.ConvertToEAN13 = false;
myReader.Decoders.I2OF5.ReportCheckDigit = false;
myReader.Actions.SetParameters();
```

С такими параметрами штрихкоды считываются в демо-приложениях Motorol'ы на ура, но не в моем.

Делал проверку аля:

```
if (_scnAPI.Reader.Decoders.I2OF5.Enabled == true)
{
    if (_scnAPI.Reader.Decoders.I2OF5.MinimumLength == 6)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("6");
    }

    if (_scnAPI.Reader.Decoders.I2OF5.MaximumLength == 8)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("8");
    }

    if (_scnAPI.Reader.Decoders.I2OF5.Redundancy == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Redundancy");
    }

    if (_scnAPI.Reader.Parameters.CodeIdType == Symbol.Barcode.CodeIdTypes.None)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("CodeType");
    }

    if (_scnAPI.Reader.Decoders.I2OF5.CheckDigitScheme == Symbol.Barcode.I2OF5.CheckDigitSchemes.None)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("CheckDigit");
    }
    if (_scnAPI.Reader.Parameters.ScanType == Symbol.Barcode.ScanTypes.Foreground)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("foreground");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("App Exit!");
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Все параметры передаются, и не ясно почему не происходит считывания, ведь передаю те же параметры при которых демо-приложение читает на ура...

Пользуюсь штатной библиотекой Symbol.Barcode, Motorola EMDK 2.8 for .NET само приложение написано на EMDK 2.4, посмотрел его спецификацию версия 2.4 совместима с 9100- серией.